# Adding an empty option-field in a select-field made by the Model

Tags: php, cakephp

My model *User* has a **belongsTo** relationship with *Country*. So when I add

```
$this->Form->input('country');
```

in *register.ctp* for example, a selectfield of countries is shown.

```
<select name="foo">
  <option value="germany">Germany</option>
  <option value="finland">Finland</option>
  <option value="usa">USA</option>
</select>
```

So my question is: Is there a cakeway of getting an empty optionfield as first in the selectfield?

Like:

```
<select name="foo">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="germany">Germany</option>
  <option value="finland">Finland</option>
  <option value="usa">USA</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
$this->Form->input('country', array('empty'=>'Select a country'));
```

Comment: note: this will add en "empty" key - if you need an integer 0 key, use 'empty'=>array(0=>'Select a country') !

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->Form->input('country',array('empty'=>'No country'));
```